# Conditional density under conditional indepencence?

Tags: conditional-probability, density-function, conditional-independence

Let $X,Y,Z$ three random variables such that the joint density can be factorized as
$$f(x,y,z) = f(x \mid z) f(y\mid z) f(z).$$
This is, I am assuming conditional independence of $X$ and $Y$ given $Z$. Let $W = I(X<Y)$, where $I$ is the indicator function, be another random variable. Is the following conditional density correct?
$$f(x,y,z\mid w=1) = f(x \mid z, w = 1) f(y\mid z, w = 1) f(z \mid w = 1).$$

Comment: No, it's not true. This is similar to this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/414045/183634 . Consider, x = c + z, y = d + z, w = c + d, c and d are unconditionally independent. Then, if w = 1, c and d become dependent. For example, if we know c=0.5, then, we know d=0.5.

Comment: @user2522806 I think this question is different as I am not assuming independence of the variables but conditional independence and then I condition on another variable $W$.

Comment: Read the first comment again. I give a counter-example to the validity of the decomposition in the question.

Comment: @user2522806 Your example makes sense, under your own assumptions, but it does not apply to my context as you can see from the definition of w.

Comment: My bad. Yes, since you have made W depend on X and Y, the conditional independence will not hold. This is the requirement: W shouldn't depend on X and Y.